# Alignment requirement of function pointers

Tags: c++, alignment, function-pointers

We know that the value of a pointer to data should be properly aligned. For example, the value of a pointer to `double` should be a multiple of 8. So I'm wondering whether a pointer to function has similar requirements.

Comment: Isn't this machine dependent? The allignment of a `double` is an optimization, so a processor can load it faster.

Comment: Completely implementation-dependent. `double` doesn't have guaranteed 8-byte alignment, either.

Comment: What you mean is that a function pointer has alignment requirement (which is implementation-defined though)?

Comment: As far as the language itself is concerned, only objects have alignment. Functions don't.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Of course it is. When I wrote my first comment I thought the OP meant (1) "does a pointer to function have alignment requirements like a `double`", but when I read it again for my second comment I thought they meant "does the value of a pointer to function have alignment requirements like the value of a pointer to object"?

Comment: @T.C. Yep, that's exactly what I thought, in that order. That's why I immediately deleted my comment, hoping you wouldn't see it, thereby exposing my foolishness.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alignment of both data and code is highly machine dependent.

On many processors, reading for example `double` at unaligned addresses will cause a fault (hardware exception, trap, or whatever you want to call it) - this either is handled in software [slow, often 10-1000x slower than aligned access] or causes the application performing the operation to fail (similar to accessing invalid memory locations in a modern OS). On for example x86, it will be slower, but typically not fail, because the processor will, at least in some cases, have to do two smaller read operations and combine those before it gets the value of the `double`.

Code may have alignment as well. Most RISC processors have fixed size code-words - 4 bytes being a commmon size, and they should be aligned to that size. ARM in "thumb" mode uses 2-byte instruction size, with some instructions having extra data in another word after.

On the other hand, x86 has "single byte" alignment requirement, and 68K for example would require code to be aligned at 2 bytes only. So in that respect, the alignment need will vary. Beyond that, there are efficiency reasons to have a certain alignment - for example starting functions/branches at 8, 16 or 32-byte boundaries is often beneficial, and I know that some older x86 processors had limits of "how many branch predictions for a given N bytes of code there could be" - meaning that if you have many different branches in a short piece of code, some would have to go without branch prediction, because the "slots" for that location were already full up.

So, compilers will (sometimes) pad code to align functions for performance reasons. However, this is not ALWAYS a win - it wastes cache-space with "padding", and it really depends on how the code is used. Compilers typically know this, at least if you use feedback/profile based optimisations (where the code is run with instrumentation to count how the code is used, and the optimisation is based on the results of this).

As a rule, however, function pointers can point anywhere that is a legal address for "code", so the fundamental requirement is typically 1, 2 or 4 bytes, based on the architecture of the processor itself.